# kdeplot with seaborn don't show up

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, seaborn, data-science

i'm trying to plot a kde, i check the sintaxis and its all good, but i think that the problenm are the axes as you see in the first image the x axis go from -0.04 yo 0.04, now if i plot just 1 variable i show a curve but the values on the axis change.

This is a sample from the DataSet i'm using

```
     AudienceRatings  CriticRating
0.0             81.0          87.0
1.0             44.0           9.0
2.0             52.0          30.0
3.0             84.0          93.0
4.0             70.0          55.0
5.0             63.0          39.0
6.0             71.0          40.0
7.0             57.0          50.0
8.0             48.0          43.0
9.0             93.0          93.0
```

In this link you will find the data set i'm using and the jupyter notebook in case more information is needed

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: works fine on my system.

Comment: Do you have the latest versions of matplotlib and seaborn installed?

Comment: @JohanC you are right, I update anaconda and seaborn to the last version

Answer (score 1):

When I type it as
`k1=sns.kdeplot(df["AudienceRatings"],df["CriticRating"])`it automatically defines x=(0,250) y=(-50,150).

If it didn't work, you can write it this way.

```
k1=sns.kdeplot(df["AudienceRatings"],df["CriticRating"])
k1.set_xlim(0,150)
k1.set_ylim(-50,150)
```